# Encoding - Pydev changes character automatically

Tags: eclipse, encoding, utf-8, pydev, jython

I am encoding every py script in my project to utf-8, as we are definitely migrating our application from Jython 2.2.1 to Jython 2.5.2. For that reason, I have added a 'magic comment' at the first line of every py file (`#encoding=utf-8`) and I have started testing whether everything is OK by debugging the application in Eclipse.

The problem appears in a script that contains the string `straße`, because it is automatically converted to `straÃŸe`.

My doubt is if this change is caused by Pydev or it happens because utf-8 doesn't cover this kind of characters. 
What can I do to automatically avoid this issue with other 'strange' strings I haven't detected yet?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your .py files use UTF-8 encoding? Try to open it with WebBrowser (as text) and check various encodings. While you see `straÃŸe` if seems that `ß` is encoded by two bytes (most probably UTF-8) but ensure it is really UTF-8.

Also check in Eclipse settings on Project/Properties. There is Resource panel with "Text file encoding" setting (I use Eclipse only for Java projects and do not know if Pydev uses this setting).

Try such code with PyDev and check if result file contains UTF-8 text:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import codecs

f = codecs.open('strasse.txt', 'wb', 'UTF-8')
f.write('straße'.decode('UTF-8'))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you had a different encoding at that file (say **cp1252**, which is the default windows encoding) and when you put **utf-8** it became garbled (so, it wasn't really PyDev who garbled it, but the fact that it was previously in another encoding).

While you're at it, also make sure you also set the default encoding for Eclipse to **utf-8** (which is usually the default platform encoding) -- you can do this at **preferences > general > workspace**.

As a note, I believe the most common way of putting that comment is `#coding: utf-8`, followed by `#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` (i.e.: not `#encoding:utf-8`) -- although all those formats work (see pep: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)